# 'Build with Parameters' in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I'm migrating a Jenkins CI job to TeamCity, and cannot find an equivalent to the 'Build with Parameters' of Jenkins in TeamCity. I've built my pipeline as follows:

1. There is a `BuildType` called `ScriptBuildType(script: String)` which runs the provided script, and attaches a VCS with a configuration parameter `%my.vcs.branch%` for the VCS's branch.
2. There is a sub-project called `MySubProject` runs a chain of `ScriptBuildType`'s:

```
sequential {
    ScriptBuildType("script 1...")
    ScriptBuildType("script 2...")
    parallel {
        ScriptBuildType("script 3...")
        ScriptBuildType("script 4...")
    }
    ScriptBuildType("script 5")
}.buildTypes()
```

When I go to TeamCity UI and running the last `ScriptBuildType` with some value for `%my.vcs.branch%`, it's indeed running with the provided value, but all the rest in the build chain (its dependencies) are running with the default value of `%my.vcs.branch%`.

How can I run the entire build chain with a value that I define for `%my.vcs.branch%`?

Answer (score 0):

Special syntax is required for passing build parameters both up and down your build chain. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2023.05/predefined-build-parameters.html#Dependency+Parameters.

If you want to pass parameters **down** the build chain:

> In a dependent build, that is later in the chain, dependency
> parameters of the previous builds have the following format:
>
> `dep.<btID>.<parameter_name>`

You can also pass parameters **up** the build chain. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2023.05/predefined-build-parameters.html#Overriding+Dependency+Parameters.

> It is possible to override values of build parameters of the
> snapshot-dependency builds in the current build, on its start.
>
> For example, build configuration A depends on B and B depends on C.
>
> On triggering, A can change any parameter used in B or C by setting
> the following parameter:
>
> `reverse.dep.<btID>.<parameter_name>`

Based on your scenario here's my assumption:

- Script 5 is dependent upon script 4
- Script 4 is dependent upon script 3 and script 2
- Both script 3 and script 2 are dependent upon script 1

In script 5 you need to add a dependency to script 4. In script 4 you'd add a dependency to scripts 3 and 2. In scripts 3 and 2 you'd add a dependency to script 1. This sets up the entire build chain.
You then add a `reverse.dep.<btID>.my.vcs.branch` to script 5 where  is the build configuration ID of script 4, and set the value of that parameter to `%my.vcs.branch%`.
You would repeat this process for scripts 4, 3, and 2 (using the correct  values).

It might be possible (preferred) to add `reverse.dep.<btID>.my.vcs.branch` for scripts 4, 3, 2, and 1 to script 5, but I've not tried it so YMMV.